# Github Move code from old repo to new repo retaining commit history

Tags: git, github

Old Repo Directory Structure

```
old-repo
\-- apple
\-- mango
\-- banana
```

New Repo Directory Structure

```
new-repo
\-- vegetables
\-- fruits
    \-- apple
    \-- mango
    \-- banana
```

Need to move contents of old repo to new repo with different structure with maintaining commit history from old repo.

Comment: How about simply creating a commit in the old repository where you move the folders into the fruits folder, and then merge this repo into the new one? If you want to get rid of other stuff in the old repo, and not move/copy that to the new repo, I would suggest making a copy of the old repo, cleaning it up with things like filter-branch or similar, and then doing the move commit with merge.